# How to prove that $\{(s, t) \in \mathbb R^2 : s \le t \le s+1 \text{ and } t \in A\}$ is a Borel set?

Tags: real-analysis, measure-theory, borel-sets

I'm doing an exercise in which I need to apply Fubini–Tonelli theorem on a non-negative function $f$. So I have to check that $f$ is measurable. However, it turns out that applying the definition of Borel $\sigma$-algebra to a specific example is not as easy as I thought.

> Let $A$ be a Borel subset of $\mathbb R$. We define
> $$
> \begin{align*}
> B &:= \{(s, t) \in \mathbb R^2 : s \le t \le s+1 \text{ and } t \in A\} , \\
> C &:= \{(s, t) \in \mathbb R^2 : s \le t \le s+1 \text{ and } s \in A\}.
> \end{align*}
> $$

Could you provide some hints to prove that $B,C$ are Borel subsets of $\mathbb R^2$?

Comment: Let $D = \{ (s,t) | s \le t \le s+1 \}$, it is straightforward to see that $D$ is Borel. Similarly we can show that $\mathbb{R} \times A$ is Borel. Then $B = D \cap (\mathbb{R} \times A) $ is Borel.

Comment: @copper.hat what is "$S$"?

Comment: @FShrike Typo. I started with $S$ and then thought it would be confusing with $s$ as a variable but didn't clean up.

Comment: @copper.hat Could you post your comment as an answer?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Let $D = \{ (s,t) | s \le t \le s+1 \}$, it is straightforward to see that $D$ is Borel. Similarly we can show that $\mathbb{R} \times A$ is Borel. Then $B = D \cap (\mathbb{R} \times A) $ is Borel.